# How do you suggest to solve this ODE analytically?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following ODE system

$\omega''(t)+\alpha\left(f(t) \omega'(t)-f'(t)\omega(t)\right)=0,  $

$\omega(\infty)\rightarrow 0,   \omega(0)=1,$

with

$f(t)=\mu+\beta t-2b\beta\left(1-e^{-t/b}\right),$

where $\alpha, \mu, \beta, a, b $ are scalars.

By introducing $z=e^{-t/b},$ I reduced the ODE into the following format

$z^2 \omega''(z)+\left(1-(\mu \alpha b+\alpha b^2 x-2\alpha b^2 \beta+2\alpha b^2\beta z)\right)z\omega'(z)-\alpha b^2 \beta \left(1-2z\right)\omega (z)=0,$

$\omega (0)=0, \omega (1)=1.$

Its straightforward to handle this ODE in the absence of the very last term (involving $\omega (z)$), however with $\omega (z),$ I don't know how to deal with it. Is there any way to solve it analytically?

Comment: It is unlikely it is solvable analytically. What exactly is your underlying goal here? It may be possible to answer some questions about the solutions without actually solving it.

Comment: It is better to get more views on whether it's solvable or not. I'd be glad to know about any suggestions on solutions.

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Partial answer:**

Making a few substitutions for those constants, we have an equation of the form

$$ z^2\omega'' + rz\omega' + (pz+q)\omega = 0 $$

which has general solution

$$ \omega = z^\frac{1-r}{2}\left[ C_1 J_\nu(2\sqrt{pz}) + C_2 Y_\nu(2\sqrt{pz}) \right] $$

with $\nu = \sqrt{(1-r)^2 - 4q}$. $J$ and $Y$ are the Bessel functions of the first and second kind, respectively. $C_1$ and $C_2$ are arbitrary constants.

---

Sources:

https://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0215.pdf

**Kamke, E.,** *Differentialgleichungen: Lösungsmethoden und Lösungen, I, Gewöhnliche Differentialgleichungen,* B. G.
Teubner, Leipzig, 1977.

**Polyanin, A. D. and Zaitsev, V. F.,** *Handbook of Exact Solutions for Ordinary Differential Equations, 2nd Edition,* Chapman
& Hall/CRC, Boca Raton, 2003.

Comment: Thank you for this one, a closer one I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Hint is:
$$
\omega''(t)+\alpha\left(f(t) \omega'(t)-f'(t)\omega(t)\right)=0,
\\
\omega''(t)+\alpha\cdot{f^2(t)}\cdot\left(\frac{\omega(t)}{f(t)}\right)'=0.
$$

Comment: This becomes second order ODE and further will need some extra steps to get to the solution. Nice